# Google Sheets- Query to Find Account Balance at the End of the Week

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, aggregate

I have a table with some checking account data in it. It looks like this:

Columns F and G, respectively

| Balance | Week Number |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 11 |
| 45 | 12 |
| 85 | 13 |
| 45 | 14 |
| 85 | 14 |
| 125 | 15 |
| 85 | 15 |
| 125 | 16 |
| 85 | 16 |
| 125 | 17 |
| 85 | 18 |
| 125 | 18 |
| 165 | 19 |
| 205 | 20 |
| 165 | 20 |
| 65 | 20 |

I get week number by using WEEKNUM() on the column with the date in it. I am trying to find a way to get the last value for each week. I've tried `"SELECT MAX(F), G GROUP BY G ORDER BY G ASC"` but there are some weeks where the last value is not the highest (such as week 15).

EDIT: Sorry about the table formatting, it looks fine in the preview. Basically, I have two columns, one with account balance, and one with the week number of the transaction

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach **`(not query-based)`** :*

```js
=reduce(F1:G1,unique(tocol(G2:G,1)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(xlookup(c,G:G,F:F,,,-1),c))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
=MAP(UNIQUE(G:G),LAMBDA(w,{XLOOKUP(w,G:G,F:F,,2,-1),w}))
```